# htaccess rewritecond help rewrite to /en/blog/ to /blog/en/ in scalable pattern

Tags: php, .htaccess

**We want to redirect all requests to this machine that do not start with /blog to start with /blog**

Currently this does not work with `/en/blog` but does work with `/en/blog/`

An example of this would be `/en/blog/` `/blog/en/`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/blog/?(.*)$   /blog/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

I must also ensure a trailing slash is added to the redirects. I'm not sure how to approach this. Whether it should be another condition in this block or another block.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the rule like that:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/blog(/.*)?$   /blog/$1$2      [P]`

This makes the trailing slash optional.

Comment: Ok thanks. I actually just figured this out myself. I am making an edit to the question as I now must ensure the trailing slash.